# Apache2 Django - Remote MySQL Access Denied 1045 (28000)

Tags: python, mysql, django, mongodb, apache2

Im having troubles to access from a Ubuntu Server using Apache2 to a remote MySQL/MongoDB database with python-mysql-connector.

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 143490:tid 140602848225021] [remote 10.242.2.3:62831] 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db-mycon-read'@'176.69.189.21' (using password: YES)
```

Apache2 .conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...

        WSGIDaemonProcess Kompetenzauswertung python-path=/home/mycadmin/Kompetenzauswertung python-home=/home/mycadmin/Kompetenzauswertung/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup Kompetenzauswertung
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mycadmin/Kompetenzauswertung/Kompetenzauswertung/wsgi.py
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**What doesnt work**:

- connecting via apache2 service

**What works**:

- connecting from my pc via tcp
- connecting via commandline on Ubuntu Server
- connecting via python-mysql-connector using a simple python script on Ubuntu Server

**Other Information:**

- Django Runs a website that needs to fetch data from a remote db (**Website has no ssl cert**)
- DEBUG is set to FALSE